# TypeError: Not all arguments converted during string formatting. Why I only get it when don't place a index number in the initial list

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm trying to get a program where:

- When the number is divisible by 3 then instead of printing the number it should print "Fizz".
- When the number is divisible by 5, then instead of printing the number it should print "Buzz".
- And if the number is divisible by both 3 and 5 e.g. 15 then instead of the number it should print "FizzBuzz"

I start the program with a list

```
lista = []
for numero in range(1,101):
  lista.append(numero)
```

The problem is that when I place: `list = [0]` it works but if I put `list =[]` it mark that error.

this is my program:

```
lista = []
for numero in range(1,101):
    lista.append(numero)

for numero2 in lista:
    if numero2 % 3 == 0 and numero2 % 5 ==0:
        lista[numero2] = "FizzBuzz"
    elif numero2 % 3 ==0:
        lista[numero2] = "Fizz"
    elif numero2 % 5 == 0:
        lista[numero2] = "Buzz"

for final in lista:
    print(final)
```

Comment: I don't see where this is happening in this code, but this almost certainly means one of the left-hand operands to `%` is a string, not an integer (`%` has multiple purposes depending on the types of operands). It doesn't appear to happen in this code though because `numero2` is the only variable that's a left-hand operand to `%`, and `numero2` should always be an integer according to this code. Please format your code properly and show the full error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please fix the formatting of your code. See: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Oh, nevermind, you're doing `lista[numero2] = "FizzBuzz"`, which overwrites elements of `lista` with a string. You're overwriting the following element with a string since `lista` starts at 1.

Comment: You're using the values of the list as indexes, so they'll be off by one since the values start at `1` but indexes start at `0`..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lista = []


for numero in range(1, 101):
    lista.append(numero)


for i in range(len(lista)):
    if lista[i] % 3 == 0 and lista[i] % 5 == 0:
        lista[i] = "FizzBuzz"
    elif lista[i] % 3 == 0:
        lista[i] = "Fizz"
    elif lista[i] % 5 == 0:
        lista[i] = "Buzz"


for final in lista:
    print(final)
```

Comment: But how does this explain why they get the mentioned error in the specific case and not in the other case?